# chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir not working

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I try to play with a same-origin check. I try to use command `chromium-browser --user-data-dir --disable-web-security` from this link to turn of same origin policy on chromium `Version 57.0.2987.133 Fedora Project (64-bit)`.

I try to get url from opened window:

```
`   function dengerClick(){
        console.log("denger click");
        var userWindow = window.open("https://google.com");
        window.setInterval(function(){
            console.log(userWindow.location.href)
        }, 5000);
    }
```

but still get the cross-origin error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at file:///home/user/jsSecurityTest.html:10:48
```